# Vertically concatenate columns from different tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got several tables, which share the same columns. I need to create a query/view where I vertically concatenate these columns. In addition, I need a second column that holds the name of the table where the particular value is coming from.

Here's my toy schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (ID INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (ID INTEGER);
```

Let's assume the tables hold the following values:

```
table_1
ID
1
2
3

table_2
ID
4
5
2
```

My result should look like this:

```
table_result
ID     SourceTable
1      table_1
2      table_1
3      table_1
4      table_2
5      table_2
2      table_2
```

Comment: What if the same id is in both tables?  Would you want it twice in the result set?

Comment: Yes indeed. I edited my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select id, 'table_1' as sourcetable
from table_1
union all
select id, 'table_2' as sourcetable
from table_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, 'table_1' AS SourceTable FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'table_2' AS SourceTable FROM table_2
```

Note, this is preferred to just using `UNION` as that ***also*** removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` doesn't expend any resources trying to de-duplicate anything.